# Deserializing .json into C# with { get; set; } (Newtonsoft)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to fill 2 strings I have from a json file using Newtonsoft.Json.
From what I have been reading, it appears as this should be working.

In my program class:

```
public string Lavalinkpw { get; set; }
public string Token { get; set; }
```

In my main task:

```
var setup = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Program>(File.ReadAllText(@"config.json"));
```

Now, I have console relaying the setup back to me (that is why it is variabialized) and it is deserializing just fine, so why is Lavalinkpw and Token not being set?
Here is the .json:

```
{
  "Lavalinkpw": "mypw",
  "Token" : "mycooltoken"
}
```

Comment: The simplest way to debug this is to serialize `new Program { Lavalinkpw = "mypw", Token = "mycooltoken" }` and see what it thinks the JSON should be. I suspect it is expecting camelcase property names; this would tell you for sure whether that's the case.

Comment: Please post an [mcve], it is impossible for us to tell *exactly* what you're doing here.

Comment: Your issue is not quite clear. Are you expecting the properties in your main Program to be set? Or are you reading that `setup` instance? Deserializing works by creating *new* instances, it will not update some existing instance

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the class name `Program` is clashing with the name of the class created by default as the container for your entry point method `Main`, so that your code is trying to deserialize to totally the wrong class. There should be a compiler warning if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

> It's possible that the class name Program is clashing with the name of
> the class created by default as the container for your entry point
> method Main, so that your code is trying to deserialize to totally the
> wrong class. There should be a compiler warning if this is the case.
>
> @Tom W

Make a custom `class` .

```
//Custom class
public class MyClass
{
    public string Lavalinkpw { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

Now call this.

```
//To deserialize json into object
var setup = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(File.ReadAllText(@"config.json"));
```

Hopefully it works for you. For more info
[JsonConvert Reference](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm).